# How to test if certain strings existing in file are present in another file?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file `sites.txt` that is generated by a script. It's a list of host names.

I have another list of host names `sites_old.txt`.

I need to check whether any of the host names present in the `sites.txt` are present in `sites_old.txt`.

I tried following but failed:

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -Fxq "$sites.txt" sites_old.txt

then
        found something// 
else
        not found//
fi
```

I also tried for but failed. I know I'm not using the statements correctly.

Comment: You're missing a switch that tells `grep` to get the patterns/strings from a file...

Comment: You'll want to read the man pages for bash, grep, and the built in test. This is not a working script.

Comment: @jdv - why would you need the builtin test ? this is a functional script and should work OK when grep is used with the right option.

Comment: @jdv, the only problem is with the `grep` command (should be `grep -Fxqf sites.txt sites_old.txt`). There's no need for a `test` command here (though reading the man pages wouldn't harm of course).

Comment: Because it makes it clearer what we are doing here. It is idiomatic shell scripting and good practice.

Comment: @jdv - not sure what you mean... it is _very clear_ what OP is doing here. Needlessly complicating things is anything but good practice.

Comment: Actually, I'd probably collect $? earlier and use that, as it's easier to test and debug. Experience will show that little scripts grow up and get complicated fast. For a one-off, do whatever you want, but good habits are worth investing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `fgrep -f` or `grep -F -f`:

```
if grep -Fxq -f "$sites.txt" sites_old.txt
then
      : found something
else
      : nothing found
fi
```

Comment: Both fgrep -f and grep -F -f worked perfect. Thanks!